# GAUL and NUTS Conversion

Tags: csv, mapping, gis

I have a dataset with location codes from the NUTS and from the GAUL system. I want to map the count of x in different regions worldwide. I downloaded the NUTS code [from](https://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/de/web/gisco/geodata/reference-data/administrative-units-statistical-units/nuts). I do have the point coordinates but the locations are on differnet levels. I have a mix of Gaul1, Gaul2, Gaul3 and NUTS1, NUTS2 and NUTS3 codes, so I'll probably have to create multiple layers with different levels.

I wonder how I can convert NUTS into GAUL code? Is there a conversion table available open source? Looked everywhere but couldn't find one... OR can I convert the location codes into an esri shape (polygon)?

Comment: NUTS can be downloaded in SHP format. You could use gdal tools to combine the SHP files or convert to a different format. I'm not familiar with the GAUL system, however if you can export the data in a well known format you can use the gdal tools to manipulate the data. This question may be better placed in the 'Geographic Information System' stackoverflow.